# Lost history of tag river-crossing-puzzle

Tags: support, bug, revision-history

The [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61545164/revisions) of [river-crossing-puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/river-crossing-puzzle) suggests that it has been created at 2020-05-01 15:09:55Z. This cannot be for there is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14551844/772868) with this tag last modified 2013. So there must be some more history which was apparently lost.

(Actually, I intended to edit the tag, and as a first step wanted to skim its history since I somewhat remember that I did that already some years ago...)

What is happening here?

Comment: There is a bug in here, but you're missing the right one. The created field [on the tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/river-crossing-puzzle/info) says it was made 6 years 7 months ago, but when hovered, it says the same date you said. I suspect there's an issue with old tags running on some legacy system that made the tag wiki itself [not be created by community](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8847948/revisions?page=3) as other tags do. It was created before the tag wiki was, but there's probably a legacy system that hasn't been fully updated